# How index a partial field content in solr

Tags: solr

Is there a way to create an index in SOLR on a partial content of a field?

For example assume we have a field like this:

```
<field name="document_text"><![CDATA[
<h1>This is my title</h1>
<p>This is document content</p>
 ]] </field>
```

and we want to create and index on `<h1>` tag content only.

I had a look at the `<copyField>` directive but it is useful only for joining several fields in a single index.

I've not found any way to do it natively in SOLR.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how well-formed the input is, you can apply a copyField directive to a field defined with a PatternReplaceCharFilter as the first filter together with a regular expression removing everything that isn't enclosed within the  tags. While parsing HTML with regular expressions usually is a bad idea, it would probably work "good enough" in this case.

You can also apply a UpdateProcessor chain when indexing, where you can have more extensive code that does XPath extraction or other HTML parsing - depending on how you write that chain.